# How to fix NameError when running Python Script in Windows Command Prompt

Tags: python, python-2.7

I ran a python file, named jbA.py in windows command prompt, with the following commands, orderly:

1. python
2. jbA.py

It displays the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): 
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'jbA' is not defined
```

Can anyone help to fix the above mentioned error? Thank you.

Comment: This is a python error, not a windows error. Somewhere you are referencing a variable 'jbA' which you have not defined. Can you post the script?

Comment: There is no such variable as jbA in py file. Unfortunately I cannot share the script, because I am not the author of it. I am just an executor of it. Thank you

Comment: Close the cmd window. Open a new one. Type `python3  jbA.py` and press Enter. If that doesn't work, use `python jbA.py`. The point is, _do it as one command_. Don't type `python` on its own, that puts you in the python interpreter.

Comment: If you can’t provide a sample or adjusted script that does show the error than no possible to get the solution. One way for you is just take the code and put inan IDE and run it, this way will point where you have the issue or you can run a simple debug. Your problem is with the script or put the full path to the script. But line I said without the code or example I’m downvoting because is not meeting the requirements for a quention on SO.

Comment: The error is completely repeatable if you do the _two_ steps that the OP has done. Instead it should be a single command. The comments and answers here just detail what is a simple problem. It's not a problem with the script itself, they just try run it from within python.

Comment: I tried with python jbA.py, Following error occurred Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "jbA.py", line 7, in
    import xlwt
ImportError: No module named xlwt

Comment: Well you have solved the issue in your question. Now your script is actually running. Now you'll need to look at how to install modules, try `pip install xlwt`. If it's a module you wrote then you'll have to do more research. I'm sorry that you got some strange advice on the initial issue.

Comment: Yes I admit it and I was distracted a lot with initial answers of this post. Btw, xlwt module is not written by myself, it is already there in https://pypi.org/project/xlwt/

Comment: Hi @roganjosh I installed xlwt file with pip install xlwt. Now it says another error WindowsError: [Error 3] The system cannot find the path specified: ''

Comment: Thank you. Got it done, by calling jbA.py with arguments -i ../.

Answer (score 4):

when you type `python` you are moving to the python commandline tool. Now there is no context for your file `jbA.py`.

To execute a python file, type `python <filename>.py`.

In your case, it is `python jbA.py`. For python 3.x, you may use `python3 jbA.py`

Comment: I tried the above and ended in the error Traceback (most recent call last): File "", line 1, in NameError: name 'jbA' is not defined

Comment: Please send a snapshot of your command prompt if possible. NameError is coming from an undefined variable or a library not available. Have a keen look at it.

Comment: No, the OP is still inside the python interpreter. They either need to close the window or type `exit()` and try again. The issue is being massively overcomplicated in the answers :/

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked that python is in your Environment PATH variable list? Try typing

```
python --version
```

in your windows command prompt and see if you get an error. If it does not return a version number, it has not been added to your PATH. 
If you don't know how to do this, refer to this link - 
https://www.java.com/en/download/help/path.xml

Comment: Yes. python --version returned following value.
Python 2.7.8  Please note that I have added C:Python27/ to environment PATH variable list. Thank you

Comment: And you are trying to execute it from the directory that it is saved in, right?

Comment: Sorry, had to downvote because the answer is not useful. If he gets a Traceback, it can hardly be an issue of Windows not finding the Python executable

Comment: Yes. The script and analyzing logs are inside a folder, specified in directory.

Comment: @shmee I realize he posted that error now. Not sure if it was there originally, I think it was, but not sure so I understand why the downvote.

Comment: @DustinHammack The question has not been edited so far, it has been there from the start, Although, proper formatting would have made it easier to spot, I admit.

Answer (score 1):

To run pyhton script 
open command prompt

1) for python version greater then 3:- python3 filename.py

2) for python version 2:- python filename.py

no need to open python console